# yocto: How do I set pc-NRfutil License

Tags: yocto

Here is my BB file:

[image: python3-nrfutil_6.1.3.bb]

This is the license for the project：

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `Other/Proprietary License` license type and it is propriatary to `NordicSemiconductor`.

So, you need to set:

```
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
```

and remove `LIC_FILES_CHKSUM`.

Or, you can create a custom layer for Nordic recipes containing `custom-licenses` folder with all their custom license files and then in your `layer.conf`:

```
LICENSE_PATH += "${LAYERDIR}/custom-licenses"
```

and in your recipe:

```
LICENSE = "<license_file>"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM += "<license_file>;md5=<checksum>"
```

I think creating such layer for Nordic is up to their decision, so setting it to `CLOSED` is the best way to go in your case.